# How to show json array object in textview

Tags: android

How to add json array in textview? I want to show json array object "name" in text view. How do I do it? How to getting single element inside array? I want to print json array obect name in textview

```
        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {       


        JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");

                        txt1.setText(data2.getString("name"));
                             }



 "status":1,
 "data":
  [
  {
  "dish_id":"37",
  "name":"dish2",
  "description":"testing",

  "allergen":
  "Eggs3,walnuts",
  "image":"http:\/\/198.57.208.46\/~school\/uploads\/images\/dishes\/egg-biryani.jpg",
  "ingredient":"weqweqw23,dsfds"
  }
   ],

 "dish_nutrition":
 {"1":
    {
     "name":"Cholesterol and Diet",
     "qty":"2"
  },"2":
 {
    "name":"Cholesterol and Diet",
    "qty":"1"
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: can you make your code look more clearer ? what you've tried ?

Comment: i want to show "name":"dish2",   this value in textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the field like this:

```
school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("name")
```

For the details look it up in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)